# Djengo Error trying to run python manage.py test

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Why am I getting this error from the end of my manange.py file? I'm trying to run python manage.py test. I get this error even if the tests.py is blank. The project works fine and I'm trying to add tests.

[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO2h1.png)

Sorry about the late getback, I do have django_rest in my installed apps. here's my settings.py -

```
"""
Django settings for djangorest project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Serer datails for password reset by email

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIR = (
#   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
#)

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djangorest/media')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '04u+3)m+%o+in*5iorg*h9ze1p(tat9en8#6qkfb3#a8xty24('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}

# Custom redirect for login
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'django.contrib.auth.forms',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
    'cg',
    'djangorest',
    'multiselectfield',



]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangorest.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Dublin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
```

Here's my manage.py -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangorest.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have failed to import rest_framework library correctly. Is there somepoint in which you are trying to import this?

do you have a anything along the lines of

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework',
)
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation

Would you mind posting you Manage.py? it might make it easier :)

Comment: Manage.py available now, should have included the files with the original posts, sorry peeps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `django-rest-framework` requirement.

Make sure you have it installed, you can use `pip freeze` command to check for installed dependencies. I guess you probably have a file named `requirementes.txt` or something along those lines, try with `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all dependencies.

Comment: djangorestframework is appearing when I check the installed apps with pip freeze, Thanks tho bkupfer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `rest_framework` in your setup ?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'rest_framework',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: @ConC: Did you cross-check mentioned here ?

Comment: It is included in my installed_apps.

Comment: it is, shows up also when I check installed apps with pip freeze